# Smallest matrix average

Tags: c

so I had to write a program which will allow the input of a 2D matrix and output which of the submatrices has the smallest average.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, R, C, n, dim1, dim2;
    float **matrix;
    float sum, min;

    printf("Number of rows: ");         //big matrix dimensions
    scanf("%d", &R);
    printf("Number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &C);

    matrix = (float**)malloc(R * sizeof(float*));

    for(i = 0; i < R; i++)
        *(matrix + i) = (float*)malloc(C * sizeof(float));

    printf("Submatrix size:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            scanf("%f", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            printf("%.2f\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");


    dim1 = R - n + 1;
    dim2 = C - n + 1;
    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < dim1; i1++) {
        for(int j1 = 0; j1 < dim2; j1++) {
            sum = 0;                            // after calculating sum of a submatrix and saving it in
            // variable min, i reset it and calculate the next one
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    sum += matrix[i + i1][j + j1];
                    printf("%3f ", matrix[i + i1][j + j1]); //printing out submatrix elements
                    if(sum < min) min = sum;        //saving current sum to variable min if the condition is true
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Minimum average of a %dx%d submatrices is %f", n, n, min / (n * n));

    return 0;
}
```

However, I don't know how to calculate the sum of smallest values in this specific case, and output is always 0. I have no problem calculating the biggest average, but I don't really understand why the input is always zero, no matter what I do. I tried initialising min variable to a large number (I know it's kinda stupid and impractical) so that the value of variable sum is smaller than variable min, and the condition would be true, but that also doesn't work...

Comment: There is no 2D array (aka "matrix") in your code and nothing which can be used as one.

Comment: You've got four loops using `i1`, `j1`, `i`, `j`. At a glance, set `min` to huge value before any loops. Move the `if (sum < min) min = sum` to just after the end of your `for i` loop. AFAICT, it's only then that `sum` is set for the _entire_ submatrix

Comment: You have not initialised `min`. It must be initialised to a high number, for example `min = FLT_MAX` so the first value you encounter will be smaller (if, not, it is still the smallest). Uninitialised, your code has *undefined behaviour* and your compiler will have warned you - if you looked!

Comment: I tried initialising it and it didn't work, I moved the if condition just like Craig said and it seems to work now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `min` still needs to be initialised, as well as Craig's other advice.

Comment: Yeah, I initialised it to FLT_MAX as you said, and then moved the if condition. When I said that I tried initialising it and it didn't work, it didn't work because I didn't move the condition at the time.